# Could not load file or assembly 'PetersDatePackage'

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, peterblum

I have recently taken over an application that uses the Peter Blum Date and Time .NET control.  I copied all the files to my aspnet_client directory and when I build the application I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'PetersDatePackage' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

Do you know how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the comment in @ajadam's note...

the DLL Refresh file will only work on your machine if the dll in question exists in the same path on your machine as it did on the previous developer's machine.

You'll need to go and find the dll, and add a reference to it.

I'm assuming you've already found it, but just in case, here's a link for you to get it from the server if there is no chance of getting the copy the original developer had...

http://www.peterblum.com/DES/DateAndTime.aspx

Comment: I had to go to our development environment and copy down the DLL from there.  In our documentation there was not any indication of a required DLL file.

Answer (score 2):

Without further details it seems like you may be missing a reference to the package. Was there a .dll and did you place it in your current project's bin folder?

Comment: No, there ia only a DLL refresh file